# Text from input into the picture

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to take text from input, for start is there "YOUR ENEMY!" and this text I need to place into the picture what I am showing. I want to just click button and the button will show pic and on that pic will be text(also I need to edit position of that text a little bit) its possible to do CSS style what will use my positions and then use them on var en? Also is it possible to click that button multiple times and everytime when I change text in input it will take new text, delete or hide pic with old text and show pic with new text.

```
Enemy: <input type="text" value="YOUR ENEMY!" id="enemy">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="BEAT UP YOUR ENEMY" onclick="dinos()"/>
    <br>
    <img id="loadingImage" src="dino.gif" style="visibility:hidden"/>
    <script>
    function dinos()
    {
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
    var en = document.getElementById("enemy").value; 
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use the z-index CSS property?

```html
ENEMY: <input type="text" value="YOUR ENEMY!" id="enemy">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="BEAT UP YOUR ENEMY" onclick="dinos()"/>
    <br>
    <img id="loadingImage" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" style="visibility:hidden"/>
<label style="z-index: 10; position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 100px;" id="LOL">Enemy's name</label>
    <script>
    function dinos()
    {
    document.getElementById('loadingImage').style.visibility='visible';
    var en = document.getElementById("enemy").value; 
      document.getElementById("LOL").innerHTML = en;
    }
    </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you want to set a default text in a textbox, then use placeholder="" instead of value